# Auto incrementing part of a composite key

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

Currently I have a composite-primary key consisting of (user, id). My user is John Smith and there are say 30 rows that pertain to him, hence id auto increments each time a new entry is made. 
 However, if i wanted to add a new user, say Jill Smith to the same table, is there a way in which I can start at (Jill Smith, 1) and have the id auto increment without messing up the previous entries?

Comment: It sounds like your database could be normalized a bit; without more details it sounds like you should only have one entry in your user column for John Smith and might need a junction table to join the user key to the referencing data. That would also indirectly solve the autoincrement problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL cannot have multiple "states" to keep track of multiple counters. To have the described behaviour, you need to implement your own application logic (w/o using the autoincrement feature) and calculate the number part of the key before inserting new rows.

**UPDATE**

The above is true in general in MySQL but how `AUTO_INCREMENT` works depends on the storage engine.

The documentation is quite specific on your particular scenario for **MyISAM** tables:

> If the AUTO_INCREMENT column is part of multiple indexes, MySQL
>   generates sequence values using the index that begins with the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column, if there is one. For example, if the animals
>   table contained indexes PRIMARY KEY (grp, id) and INDEX (id), MySQL
>   would ignore the PRIMARY KEY for generating sequence values. As a
>   result, the table would contain a single sequence, not a sequence per
>   grp value.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html